# If statements with or

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to test for files and if would like it to test for all of them and when one does not exist then it will do code. I tried the `||` but it doesn't seem to work so I was wondering if it's the right one that I need to be using.

Example:

```
    if (File.Exists("//1.txt") || File.Exists("//2.txt") || File.Exists("//3.txt") )
    {
        //DO NOTHING
    }
    else
    {
    File.Create("//1.txt");
    File.Create("//2.txt");
    File.Create("//3.txt"); 
    }
```

so,

if (This(Which is true) or This(Which is true) or This (Which is FALSE))
{

}

Comment: You need `&&` not `||`

Comment: i think you mean && if you want to test for all of them

Comment: Why is this downvoted ?  it is a question

Comment: Can you please explain more specifically what *exactly* you are trying to do?

Comment: I think your `||` is correct but you just have a typo. The third part of your `if` shouldn't be `File.Exists("//3.txt")` ?

Comment: *when one does not exist* - Your code is checking if they do exist, not if they don't.

Comment: *if (This(Which is true) or This(Which is true) or This (Which is FALSE))* - This results in `true` because you're using OR and at least one of the items is `true`.

Comment: So whats a way to make it come out false if one or more of them are false

Comment: The answer from ChrisF does that.

Answer (score 5):

You want "and" (`&&`) in this case.

Your current test says that if *any* of the files exist do nothing, else create all three, but you actually want the test to say if any of the files don't exist (re)create them.

Though perhaps you should be checking for each file individually so that you don't overwrite existing data.

Comment: Its not && as if i remove one of them it doesnt remake all of them

Comment: @JoshuaHodson - it should - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx - if it's not then something else is going on.

Comment: @JoshuaHodson Which one do you remove? 3.txt?

Comment: @Gruff that looks like it was just a typo in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The if statement in this case reaches the first true statement and then executes the `//DO NOTHING` portion.  If your goal is to have it recreate all 3 files in the event of one or all of them not existing you want to do:

```
if (!File.Exists("//1.txt") || !File.Exists("//2.txt") || !File.Exists("//3.txt") )
{
    File.Create("//1.txt");
    File.Create("//2.txt");
    File.Create("//3.txt"); 
}
```